# Occurs check: cannot construct the infinte type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to construct a list of all prime numbers using the sieve method:

```
primes remNum =
  let i = head remNum
  in i : primes (filter (\(x) -> x mod i /= 0) (tail remNum))
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
    t ~ (a -> a -> a) -> t -> a1
  Expected type: [t]
    Actual type: [(a -> a -> a) -> t -> a1]
* In the first argument of `head', namely `remNum'
  In the expression: head remNum
  In an equation for `i': i = head remNum
* Relevant bindings include
    i :: t (bound at lib.hs:30:7)
    remNum :: [(a -> a -> a) -> t -> a1] (bound at lib.hs:29:8)
    primes :: [(a -> a -> a) -> t -> a1] -> [t] (bound at lib.hs:29:1)
```

I don't understand why remNum is bound to `[(a-> a -> a) -> t -> a1]` while `i` is bound to `t`, since surely `head :: [a] -> a` would imply `remNum::[t]`?

So the idea with this is that it is supplied a lazy list of all numbers and then essentially maintains a list of removed values.

It would be called:

```
numsFrom n = n : numsFrom (n + 1)
primes numsFrom 2
```

Comment: *all* prime numbers?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x mod i
```

is not what you intended. You want to use

```
x `mod` i
```

The problem with the first is that since both `i` and `x` are from the list, they must have the same type. Let's call that type  `X`. What is `X`? Well, since we use `x mod`, it should start with `mod`'s type:

```
type X = (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> …
```

Since the other "parameter" is `i`, which has the same type as `x`, we end up with:

```
type X = (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> X -> …
```

which is an infinite type.

So the proper solution would be

```
primes remNum =
  let i = head remNum
  in i : primes (filter (\(x) -> x `mod` i /= 0) (tail remNum))
```

or

```
primes remNum =
  let i = head remNum
  in i : primes (filter (\(x) -> mod x i /= 0) (tail remNum))
```

or (with pattern matching)

```
primes (i:remNums) = x : primes (filter (\x -> mod x i /= 0) remNums)
```

Comment: This is because mod is an infix operator? I'm pretty new to haskell so...

Comment: @Cjen1 no. `mod` is a function. You can use backticks to make it an infix one.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was what I meant